# Replace FTP servers with AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am planning to migrate large files in on-premises FTP servers to AWS S3. We have about 300 staff. Each of them have access to a S3 folder to upload and download files.

My plan is to create a single S3 bucket, create IAM user for each employee. Put the IAM users in a group that has an IAM policy that permits access to sub directories within the bucket via use of the username policy variable. Is it feasible? or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have active directory or an existing authentication provider?

Comment: No, we do not have AD.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your FTP server already has user authentication (either native or active directory) you should stick with the existing user authentication scheme, and let IAM control access to the S3 resources at the bucket wide level.

While IAM is designed to control access to AWS resources,  it is *not* intended for user level authentication across 3rd party application servers. Use the current user authentication method implemented by your FTP server.

Use IAM permissions to grant access from the FTP server to the S3 bucket. This is the role IAM would play in this type of implementation: limit access to the AWS resource to the service providing access only.

Then, use a mount S3-bucket-as-drive driver (CloudBees, s3Fs, TNTdrive etc) and map each users home directory to a driver mapping to the users bucket in S3.

So if your S3 bucket is s3://my-ftp-server, give your FTP server read write access to that bucket via IAM.  In the ftp sever, mount the S3 bucket to a drive or file system (say F:) and then map each users home directory to their individual bucket key (eg f:\john_smith)

Comment: Thanks but our plan is to get rid of FTP servers in the near future.

Comment: ah ok - what interface will users/clients use to upload/download?

Comment: We will use S3 client. Sorry I didnt make this clear in my post.